# How to author a looping DVD?

Tags: dvd

I have used `devede` to author a DVD from an MPEG file with no menu. I've set the title to loop after it plays in the options but it doesn't actually loop in DVD players (playback simply stops). I've found this comment in a DVD FAQ:

> "Almost all features of DVD such as search, pause, and scan can be
>   disabled by the disc, which can prevent the player from searching back
>   to the beginning of a segment. If the player uses time search to
>   repeat a segment, then a disc with fancy non-sequential title
>   organization will not have timecode information the player needs to
>   search. In many cases the authors don't even realize they have
>   prevented the use of the repeat feature."

But I don't understand how I would go about adding "timecode information" or creating "sequential titles" (there is only one title) and I don't know if this is really the cause. I can use windows or linux to author the disc so if anyone has got this working I'd like to hear how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

It seems the source mpg was not being converted to a fully-compliant VOB file. I solved this with the following script that re-muxes the source file before building the DVD:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Burn an MPEG file to a DVD as a looping demo
# Author: SpliFF (www.warriorhut.org)
# License: Public Domain

# Usage: mpeg2dvdloop input_file [project_name]

# Path to input mpeg file
INPUT="$1"

# Name of DVD project (default taken from input filename)
INPUT_FILENAME="${1##*/}"
NAME="${2:-"${INPUT_FILENAME%.[^.]*}"}"

# DVD burner device (might be /dev/sr0, /dev/dvd or /dev/cdrom, etc)
DVD_DEVICE="/dev/sr0"

# Working directory (make sure it has plenty of space)
# You'll defineatly want to change this if /tmp is a tmpfs ramdisk
WD='/tmp'

echo "Creating DVD project \"$NAME\" in \"$WD\" ..."

echo -e "\nWriting dvdauthor config file to \"$WD/$NAME.xml\" ...\n"

cat > "$WD/$NAME.xml" <<_EOF_
<dvdauthor>
    <vmgm />
    <titleset>
        <titles>
            <pgc>
                <vob file="$NAME-remux.mpg" />
                <post>
                    jump title 1;
                </post>
            </pgc>
        </titles>
    </titleset>
</dvdauthor>
_EOF_

echo -e "\nExtracting audio and video to elementary streams using transcode tools ...\n"
# Gentoo package: media-video/transcode
tcextract -i "$INPUT" -d 10 -t vob -x mpeg2 > "$WD/$NAME.m2v"
tcextract -i "$INPUT" -d 10 -a 0 -x ac3 -t vob > "$WD/$NAME.ac3"

echo -e "\nMerging streams into compatible file using mjpeg tools ...\n"
# Gentoo package: media-video/mjpegtools
mplex -f 8 -o "$WD/$NAME-remux.mpg" "$WD/$NAME.m2v" "$WD/$NAME.ac3"

echo -e "\nCreating DVD structure using dvdauthor ...\n"
# Gentoo package: media-video/dvdauthor
rm -rf "$WD/$NAME-DVD" && dvdauthor -o "$WD/$NAME-DVD" -x "$WD/$NAME.xml"

echo -e "\nBurning to DVD-R using growisofs ...\n"
# Gentoo package: app-cdr/dvd+rw-tools
growisofs -v -Z "$DVD_DEVICE" -dvd-video -V "$NAME" "$WD/$NAME-DVD"
```